# Incorrect drawing with SceneKit with overlay on macOS Sierra

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit, macos-sierra

I'm using two `SCNView`'s for drawing my interface and I've a SpriteKit overlay (on the topmost `SCNView` for HUD like features. 
On macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) everything works out fine, but on 10.12 (Sierra) the overlay seems to be blended with the background's alpha.

Compare 10.11 (expected output):

[image: macOS 10.11]

With the output on 10.12:

[image: macOS 10.12 fully transparent background]

The view stack is:

- SCNView (opaque black background)
- SCNView (clear background)

  - SpriteKit overlay (partly transparent, partly opaque)

The yellow square (alpha=0.50) and red square (opaque) are from the overlay . The white cube is drawn in the topmost (transparent) `SCNView`.

When I make the background semi transparent, more of the squares becomes visible, still remaining transparent:

[image: macOS 10.12 semi transparent background]

The code for this setup is:

```
    sceneView.scene=SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 1)))

    //An overlay
    let overlayScene=SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 10))
    overlayScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

    let bar=SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5), size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 40))
    bar.anchorPoint=CGPoint.zero

    let smallBar=SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 20))
    smallBar.position=CGPoint(x: 125, y: 20)

    bar.addChild(smallBar)
    overlayScene.addChild(bar)

    sceneView.overlaySKScene=overlayScene

    //Optionally:
    sceneView.backgroundColor=NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

I could not find anything to get Sierra render the overlay correctly, like setting the blend mode of the SpriteKit scene.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this drawing problem?

Comment: Looks like an issue with linear color space. Can you try to set the key 'SCNDisableLinearSpaceRendering' to YES in your info.plist?

Comment: That gives the correct transparency behaviour. Colors are still a bit different though. I couldn't really find any real information about how it all works and why the overlay would disappear on the background with linear space rendering. Do you have some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something you're not showing us? It works for me, using projects created with either Xcode 7 or Xcode 8, on a MacBook Pro running 10.12. Maybe it's a graphic card issue?

[image]

I don't see where you're changing the blend mode of the `SKOverlay`. So it defaults to `.alpha` per docs.

To reproduce my project, start with the Xcode SceneKit game template. Remove the `mouseDown` definition from the `GameView` class. Import SpriteKit into GameViewController.swift, and replace `awakeFromNib` with this:

```
override func awakeFromNib(){
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // create a new scene
    gameView.scene=SCNScene()
    gameView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 1)))

    //An overlay
    let overlayScene=SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 10))
    overlayScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

    let bar=SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5), size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 90))
    bar.anchorPoint=CGPoint.zero

    let smallBar=SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 30))
    smallBar.position=CGPoint(x: 125, y: 50)

    bar.addChild(smallBar)
    overlayScene.addChild(bar)

    gameView.overlaySKScene=overlayScene

    //Optionally:
    gameView.backgroundColor=NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    //        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    //        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    //        gameView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    //        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLight.LightType.omni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    //        gameView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGray
    //        gameView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    self.gameView!.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    //        self.gameView!.showsStatistics = true

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please remove the last line from your `awakeFromNib()`. I think you missed the part that my (topmost) `SCNView` is transparent. Your project then shows the same behavior as mine.

Comment: Not only that, I missed the part about two different SCNViews on top of each other! Here's a revised view. I guess I'll leave this answer here but it's not a solution.

Comment: What surprises me a bit is that your new screenshot doesn't show the squares becoming transparent. When I removed your last line in my copy, the (grey) background became visible behind both squares, much like in my 3'rd screenshot.

Comment: My sample uses only a single SCNView, with overlaySKScene, instead of two SCNViews as yours does. That seems like it might be relevant but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass your SCNView, override the **viewDidMoveToWindow()** method and not call super.viewDidMoveToWindow() within that method, it may work. I had a very similar problem adding an overlaySKScene to an SCNView and this fixed the color issue. However, the view may initially flash red for some reason.